# Problems with writing into IsolatedStorageFile

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I'm trying to write data into a file using IsolatedStorageFile. The file is called "Notes". The notes file is not opened at all!

While debugging, I found that the control goes to the else condition. It creates the "Notes.txt" file, but it does not further enter into the loop. It executes the using statement and then comes out of the loop and hence the writing does not take place.

```
    public void WriteNotesToFile()
    {
        try
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile storagefile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (storagefile.FileExists("Notes"))
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = storagefile.OpenFile("Notes", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

                        for (int i = 0; i < m_dtNoteDate.Length; i++)
                        {
                            writer.Write(m_dtNoteDate[i].ToString("dd-MM-yyy");
                            writer.Write(" ");
                            writer.WriteLine(m_strNotes[i]);
                        }
                        writer.Close();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    storagefile.CreateFile("Notes.txt");
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = storagefile.OpenFile("Notes", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

                        for (int i = 0; i < m_dtNoteDate.Length; i++)
                        {
                            writer.Write(m_dtNoteDate[i]);
                            writer.Write("");
                            writer.WriteLine(m_strNotes[i]);
                        }
                        writer.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch { }
    }
```

Could somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

You create Notes.txt but check for Notes. Check for Notes.txt instead.

Comment: lemme check that, I had found another error, in the else block i had used using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = storagefile.OpenFile("Notes", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)) instead of using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = storagefile.OpenFile("Notes", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))

Comment: @alfah - If this problem is resolved you should mark an answer. If xyzzer's question helped you solve the problem, mark it as the answer. If not, add an answer yourself describing what solved the problem and mark it as the answer. Alternatively, you can delete your question.

Comment: @richard solution is my comment. but a comment cannot be marked as answer :D

Comment: Well, since elsewhere you create "Notes.txt" and you try to open "Notes" - using the same file name in both situations would be the actual fix for the question you asked and you would not need to call OpenFile with FileMode.Create. One more reason for using consts for consts (like file names) instead of repeating literals and making mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = storagefile.OpenFile("Notes", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
```

had to be used in the else block and not `FileMode.Open`